# Templated operator overload resolution, member vs non-member function

Tags: c++, templates, clang++

When trying out clang-3.4 (compiled from git), it failed to compile one of my projects complaining about ambiguity while resolving overloaded operators.
I turned out that there were two templated operators, one of which was declared as a member function, other as a non-member one, which both seems equally good match.

Following SSCCE demonstrates the situation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ostr {
        std::ostream& s;

        template<class T>
        ostr& operator<<(const T& x) { s << x; return *this; }
};

struct xy {
        double x, y;
};

template<class Stream>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, const xy& x) {
        s << "[" << x.x << ", " << x.y << "]";
        return s;
}

int main() {
        ostr os{std::cout};
        xy x{4, 5};
        os << "Value is: " << x <<"\n";
}
```

The project compiled fine before and I checked again this SSCCE with several compilers (`gcc 4.5`, `4.6`, `4.7`, `4.8` and `clang 3.3`) and all of them compiled it without any warning (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`). All compilers were set to C++11/C++0x standard.
After adding ctor to `ostr`, it compiled fine even on `MSVC 2012` and `2010`)

Making both `operator<<`s non-member exhibits the ambiguity in all compilers (as expected)

After looking through the standard drafts (`N3242` and `N3690`) I failed to find anything making member functions/operators better match than non-member ones.

So I failed to prove `clang-3.4` is wrong and I wonder who's right.
Thus my question is:

- Is this code valid? Should member operators/functions be better match than non-member ones and it's a bug in clang-3.4?
- Or are all the other compilers wrong/too permissive?

*I am aware that changing the second `operator<<` to non-templated function (with `std::ostream` instead of template parameter) would resolve the the ambiguity and work as expected, but that's not the point here.*

Comment: +1 because it's an interesting question; but I'd +1 it again if I could for your clarity and thoroughness!

Comment: "Should member operators/functions be better match than non-member ones" No, but they get as an additional parameter a reference to the type of their class just for overload resolution.

Comment: Could be related to [this clang bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17075)

Comment: DyP: That bug was supposedly fixed in r190470. I tested it with current version (r194576, commited just an hour ago) a the result is still the same.

Comment: Try using a version *before* r190470, like 184460 as used at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a778e82e17a7db55): It behaves like the other compilers.

Comment: DyP: You're right, r190470 is where it changed. I just tried 190646 (the closest commit I could get using git mirror) and it worked fine. And r190470 rejects the code the same way current version does).

Comment: Amazing, this compiler discrepancy still exists to this day with `Clang 16.0` and `GCC 13.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload resolution adds an additional parameter to a member function just for the purpose of overload resolution:

[over.match.funcs]/2

> The set of candidate functions can contain both member and non-member functions to be resolved against the same argument list. So that argument and parameter lists are comparable within this heterogeneous set, a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the *implicit object parameter*, which represents the object for which the member function has been called.

/4

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> — “lvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared without a *ref-qualifier* or with the `&` *ref-qualifier*
>
> — “rvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared with the `&&` *ref-qualifier*
>
> where `X` is the class of which the function is a member and *cv* is the *cv*-qualification on the member function declaration.

Some special rules follow, for example to allow binding an rvalue to this implicit object parameter (for calling member functions w/o ref-qualifier on rvalues, e.g. `ostr{std::cout}<<"hello"`).

---

The function signatures *including* the implicit object parameter we need to compare for overload resolution are:

```
template<class T>
ostr& ostr::operator<<(ostr&, const T&);    // F1

template<class Stream>
Stream& ::operator<<(Stream&, const xy&);    // F2
```

After substitution for `os << x`, we get the *same* signature:

```
ostr& ostr::operator<<(ostr&, const xy&);
ostr& ::    operator<<(ostr&, const xy&);
```

So only one of the "tie-breakers" in [over.match.best]/1 could resolve the ambiguity. Indeed, one could apply, namely the "`F1` is more specialized than `F2`" (or vice versa): partial ordering of function templates.

N.B. The procedure of adding an implicit object parameter is specified *again* in the description of partial ordering [temp.func.order]/3.

---

For partial ordering of `F1` and `F2` (as defined above), we first create two unique types:

```
struct unique_T {};
struct unique_Stream {};
```

Then we transform `F1` into `F1'` by replacing the template parameter `T` with the unique type `unique_T` (and similarly for `F2`):

```
ostr& ostr::operator<<(ostr&, const unique_T&);
ostr& ::    operator<<(unique_Stream&, const xy&);
```

The parameters of the transformed function `F1'` are now used to try to deduce the template parameters of the untransformed `F2`:

```
ostr a0;
unique_T a1; // no reference, no cv-qualifier
::operator<<(a0, a1) // does template argument deduction succeed?

// reminder: signature of ::operator<<
template<class Stream>
Stream& ::operator<<(Stream&, const xy&);
```

The deduction succeeds for `a0` [with `Stream` = `ostr`], therefore the type `ostr&` from `F1` is considered to be at least as specialized as type of the corresponding first parameter of `F2` (`Stream&`, with `Stream` being a template parameter). I'm not sure what happens to the second argument `a1`, since no deduction takes place for the second parameter of `::operator<<` (it is of type `const xy&`).

Now we repeat the process with arguments from `F2'` and try to deduce the template parameters of `F1`:

```
unique_Stream a0;
xy a1;
ostr::operator<<(a0, a1);

// reminder: signature of ostr::operator<<
template<class T>
ostr& ostr::operator<<(ostr&, const T&);
```

Here, no deduction occurs for the first argument, but it occurs and succeeds for the second argument [with `T` = `xy`].

I conclude no function template is more specialized. Therefore overload resolution *should fail* due to ambiguity.

Comment: Am I sure? No. Please add any hint that could help clarify the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the step by step walk-through. You made [over.match.best] much clearer for me :). So the code should be invalid and clang (after r190470) is the only one being correct? It definitely seems that way...